# Why does this function only return the last element of an array?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm a bit confused by why this function always sets the `h1#attack` to the first element of the `hero.attacks`-array, when any `li.attack` is clicked? I'm trying to make set it to the corresponding `hero.atatcks`-element's name. I've tried with both a for-loop and a foreach and an index set outside of the loop which 'm increasing for every iteration, but nothing seems to work?

http://jsfiddle.net/47r768p8/2/

Javascript:

```
var hero = {
    attacks: [{
        name: "atck1"
    }, {
        name: "atck2"
    }, {
        name: "atck3"
    }, {
        name: "atck4"
    }]
};
var attacks = document.getElementsByClassName("attack");
for (var i = 0; i < attacks.length; i++) {
    var atck = hero.attacks[i];
    attacks[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        document.getElementById("attack").innerText = atck.name;
    })
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="attack">Atck1</li>
    <li class="attack">Atck2</li>
    <li class="attack">Atck3</li>
    <li class="attack">Atck4</li>
</ul>
<h1 id="attack"></h1>
```

Comment: Actually it always returns the last one because your objects are of reference type, but because your array has same items you think it's the first one :)

Comment: I think this may be a classic case of using the same variable in a loop. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: @YauheniLeichanok Made a typo copy/pasting it from my code, anywho, it's only using the last one for some reason?

Comment: Check the link that @jwatts1980 posted - it has a great explanation.

Comment: @jwatts1980 If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it...that or should I just delete my question?

Comment: @Mobilpadde The question has been closed because it was marked as a duplicate. I was creating an answer but was not able to post it before the question was closed.

Comment: @jwatts1980 Oh, well... I wish I'd give you some points for helping me out, but if you're not able to post an answer, it's gonna be tough. (Already upvoted your comment)

Comment: Not a problem. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your array `hero.attacks` consists of the same item, iterated several times, which is why it appears that it is setting the same item every time. Try the following:

```
var hero = {
    attacks: [{
        name: "atck1"
    }, {
        name: "atck2"
    }, {
        name: "atck3"
    }, {
        name: "atck4"
    }]
};
```

Comment: God I'm stupid, anywho, it still doesn't work... Now it's only using the last one.

Comment: @Mobilpadde http://jsfiddle.net/47r768p8/3/ Here is one of possible solutions.

Comment: @YauheniLeichanok Wow, that's great! Thanks! Post it as an answer, and I'll accept it :D